# React native fetch and low connection

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an issue with a fetch (api call) on react native, when i have a low connection or temporarly lost connection.

My function :

```
async function getlastcursor(att){
  const url=base_url+"/lastcursor;
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('att', att);

  let result="";
  try {
       result=fetch(url, {
         method: 'POST',
           headers:{
             'content-type':'multipart/form-data'
           },
           body: formData,
       }).then((response) => response.json())
   } catch (error) {

   }

  return result;

}
```

If log can be help to debug me :
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 23):
TypeError: Network request failed
onerror@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:26748:31
dispatchEvent@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:32302:31
setReadyState@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31386:33
__didCompleteResponse@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31213:29
emit@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:3316:42
__callFunction@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2648:49
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2361:31
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2602:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2360:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]

I would like to retry automatically when i have a Network request failed (which is when connection is low or temporarly lost).

What can i do to make it ? Use Promise class?

Thanks you